# What are the continuous functions that satisfy the following?

Tags: probability, continuity

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x < 0 \\
1 - f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right), & x > 0\text{.}
\end{cases}$

I want this to generate a random variable that will be used as a proportion in a way that it is symmetrical to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any continuous function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1-g(\frac{1}1)$ or, equivalently, $g(1)=\frac{1}2$. This will serve as the value of $f$ in the interval $[0,1]$. The rest of $f$ follows from there, and continuity is easily shown. Define $f$ as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 && \text{if } x<0\\ g(x) && \text{if }0\leq x\leq 1 \\ 1-g(\frac{1}x)&& \text{if }1<x\end{cases}$$

There are, of course, infinitely many solutions to this, as any continuous $g$ suffices, as long as it has the proper endpoints; the functional equation isn't so strict, in that there are no relations between any two values in $[0,1]$, so we can choose those freely.

**Added:** If you don't intend that $f$ need include $0$ in its domain, then we use the same construction, except let $g$ be any continuous function $(0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $g(1)=\frac{1}2$ - so a function like $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}2$ would be admissible, where it is not if $f$ must be defined at $0$.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Based on the question, it does not seem that the question needs to be defined at zero. Of course, this does not change the character of the solution method.

Comment: @Baby I sort of figure it would be, because of continuity, though I guess the domain could be $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, in which case $g$ should be on $(0,1]$ and has no restriction on its behavior near $0$.

Comment: The word continuous in this case is simply an adjective you have to carry around with you during the argument. This might seem counterintuitive, but it is due to the fact that $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is disconnected.

Comment: Good. The function would be zero at zero, but I was not quite worried about this since all I wanted is something that I could use as a CDF for my variable. I also found 2/pi*arctan(x) as a solution if anyone is curious